# Proof of gauge invariance of the massless Fierz-Pauli action (follow-up)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, metric-tensor, field-theory, gauge-theory

*This question is a follow-up to [Proof of gauge invariance of the massless Fierz-Pauli action](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/522852/proof-of-gauge-invariance-of-the-massless-fierz-pauli-action).*

One representation of the Fierz-Pauli action (up to a prefactor) is,
$$
S[h]
=\int dx\left\{\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\lambda h^{\mu\nu})(\partial^\lambda h_{\mu\nu})}_{=:A}-\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\lambda h)(\partial^\lambda h)}_{=:B}-\underbrace{(\partial_\lambda h^{\lambda\nu})(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu})}_{=:C}+\underbrace{(\partial^\nu h)(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu})}_{=:D}\right\}.\tag{1}
$$

We now want to show that $S[h]$ is invariant under the gauge transformation,
$$
h_{\mu\nu}\rightarrow h_{\mu\nu}+\delta h_{\mu\nu},\tag{2}
$$
wherein $\delta h_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu\xi_\nu+\partial_\nu\xi_\mu$. We demand that $\xi_\mu(x_\nu)$ falls of rapidly at the respective boundaries of the action.

**i) Why is it sufficient to only consider invariance of gauge transformations up to the first-order?**
Even if we consider the weak gravity regime $h_{\mu\nu}\ll1$, I don't see how this should lead to $\delta h_{\mu\nu}\ll 1$.

We now start to show first-order invariance by applying the gauge transformation, Eq. (2), to the terms $A, B, C, D$.

$$
\begin{align}
A
&\to\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\lambda h^{\mu\nu}+\partial_\lambda \delta h^{\mu\nu})(\partial^\lambda h_{\mu\nu}+\partial^\lambda\delta h_{\mu\nu})\\
&=\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\lambda h^{\mu\nu})(\partial^\lambda h_{\mu\nu})}_{=A}+\underbrace{(\partial_\lambda h^{\mu\nu})(\partial^\lambda\delta h_{\mu\nu})}_{=\delta A}+\mathcal{O}(\delta h_{\mu\nu}^2)\\
B
&\to\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\lambda h+\partial_\lambda \delta h)(\partial^\lambda h+\partial^\lambda\delta h)\\
&=\underbrace{\frac{1}{2}(\partial_\lambda h)(\partial^\lambda h)}_{=B}+\underbrace{(\partial_\lambda h)(\partial^\lambda\delta h)}_{=:\delta B}+\mathcal{O}(\delta h_{\mu\nu}^2)\\
C
&\to(\partial_\lambda h^{\lambda\nu}+\partial_\lambda\delta h^{\lambda\nu})(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu}+\partial^\mu\delta h_{\mu\nu})\\
&=\underbrace{(\partial_\lambda h^{\lambda\nu})(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu})}_{=C}+\underbrace{2(\partial_\lambda h^{\lambda\nu})(\partial^\mu\delta h_{\mu\nu})}_{=:\delta C}+\mathcal{O}(\delta h_{\mu\nu}^2)\\
D
&\to
(\partial^\nu h+\partial^\nu\delta h)(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu}+\partial^\mu\delta h_{\mu\nu})\\
&=\underbrace{(\partial^\nu h)(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu})}_{=D}+2\underbrace{(\partial^\nu h)(\partial^\mu \delta h_{\mu\nu})}_{=:\delta D}+\mathcal{O}(\delta h_{\mu\nu}^2)
\end{align}
$$
**ii) Are these results correct so far? How do I show $(\partial^\nu h)(\partial^\mu \delta h_{\mu\nu})=(\partial^\nu\delta h)(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu})$?**

Using the previous results, we find,
$$
S[h+\delta h]-S[h]
=\int dx\left\{\delta A-\delta B-\delta C+\delta D\right\}+\mathcal{O}(\delta h^2).\tag{3}
$$
Only $\delta B$ and $\delta D$ contain $h$, therefore, both should cancel (up to a constant) and we can consider them separate,
$$
\begin{align}
\int dx\left\{\delta D-\delta B\right\}
&=\int dx\left\{2(\partial^\nu h)(\partial^\mu\delta h_{\mu\nu})-(\partial_\lambda h)(\partial^\lambda\delta h) \right\}\\
&=\int dx(\partial^\lambda h)\left\{2(\partial^\mu\delta h_{\mu\lambda})-(\partial_\lambda\delta h) \right\}\\
&=\int dx(\partial^\lambda h)\left\{2(\partial^\mu(\partial_\mu\xi_\lambda+\partial_\lambda\xi_\mu)-\partial_\lambda(2\partial^\mu\xi_\mu) \right\}\\
&=2\int dx(\partial^\lambda h)(\partial^2\xi_\lambda).\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Next, we examine the other two terms,
$$
\begin{align}
\int dx\left\{\delta A-\delta C\right\}
&=\int dx\left\{(\partial_\lambda h^{\mu\nu})(\partial^\lambda\delta h_{\mu\nu})-2(\partial_\lambda h^{\lambda\nu})(\partial^\mu \delta h_{\mu\nu})\right\}\\
&=\int dx\left\{-h^{\mu\nu}(\partial^2\delta h_{\mu\nu})+2h^{\lambda\nu}(\partial_\lambda\partial^\mu \delta h_{\mu\nu})\right\}\\
&=\int dxh^{\mu\nu}\left\{-\partial^2\delta h_{\mu\nu}+2\partial_\mu\partial^\lambda \delta h_{\lambda\nu}\right\}\\
&=\int dxh^{\mu\nu}\left\{-\partial^2(\partial_\mu\xi_\nu+\partial_\nu\xi_\mu)+2\partial_\mu\partial^\lambda (\partial_\lambda\xi_\nu+\partial_\nu\xi_\lambda)\right\}\\
&=\int dxh^{\mu\nu}\left\{\partial_\mu\partial^2\xi_\nu-\partial^2\partial_\nu\xi_\mu+2\partial_\mu\partial_\nu(\partial^\lambda\xi_\lambda)\right\},\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
wherein we used partial integration for the second equal and index relabeling for the third equal.

Comparing Eq. (4) and Eq. (5), we see that terms don't add up to a constant or divergence.
**iii) Where have I made mistakes?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A friend from university has helped me answer the questions:

i) Our gauge transformation is a linear transformation and therefore can be considered to form a Lie group. From Lie groups we know, that it is sufficient to show invariance only up to the first-order as we can always dissect transforms "large" in magnitude (think $\delta h\gg1$) into infinitesimal steps.
*If someone can put this in a more rigorous language, please do so!*

ii)+iii) Actually, $(\partial^\nu h)(\partial^\mu \delta h_{\mu\nu})\neq(\partial^\nu\delta h)(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu})$, thus, we must correct the transformation of term $D$ to,
$$
D
\to
(\partial^\nu h+\partial^\nu\delta h)(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu}+\partial^\mu\delta h_{\mu\nu})\\
=\underbrace{(\partial^\nu h)(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu})}_{=D}+\underbrace{(\partial^\nu \delta h)(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu})+ (\partial^\nu h)(\partial^\mu \delta h_{\mu\nu})}_{=:\delta D}+\mathcal{O}(\delta h_{\mu\nu}^2).
$$
Now, Eq. (4) reads,
$$
\begin{align}
\int dx\left\{\delta D-\delta B\right\}
&=
\int dx(\partial^\nu h)\left\{\partial^\mu\delta h_{\mu\nu}-\partial_\nu \delta h\right\}+\int dx (\partial^\nu \delta h)(\partial^\mu h_{\mu\nu})\\
&=\underbrace{-\int dx h\partial^2\left\{\partial^\nu\xi_\nu-\partial^\mu\xi_\mu\right\}}_{=0}-\int dx h_{\mu\nu}(\partial^\mu\partial^\nu\delta h).
\end{align}
$$
Adding up Eq. (5) and the corrected version of Eq. (4), we find that the transformed action up to first-order indeed vanishes,
$$
\begin{align}
\int dx\delta S
&=\int dx h^{\mu\nu}\left\{\partial_\mu\partial^2\xi_\nu-\partial^2\partial_\nu\xi_\mu+\underbrace{2\partial_\mu\partial_\nu(\partial^\lambda\xi_\lambda)-2\partial_\mu\partial_\nu(\partial^\lambda\xi_\lambda)}_{=0}\right\}\\
&=\int dx h^{\mu\nu}\partial^2\partial_\mu\partial^2\xi_\nu-\int dx h^{\nu\mu}\partial^2\partial_\mu\xi_\nu\\
&=\int dx h^{\mu\nu}\partial^2\partial_\mu\partial^2\xi_\nu-\int dx h^{\mu\nu}\partial^2\partial_\mu\xi_\nu
=0,
\end{align}
$$
where we have used in the last steps that $h^{\mu\nu}=h^{\nu\mu}$ and that we can relabel summed indices.